# Is there a way to keep the Dockerfile in sync with project references (C# .NET)

Tags: c#, docker

I am using Visual Studio and JetBrains Rider to develop my projects.
I have a solution with multiple projects (libraries). One if them is the application project which has project references to the others.

When I add Docker Support for the first time everything is fine.
But when I add a new library and reference that from my application project I need to add this entry to the Dockerfile manually, e.g:

```
COPY ["NewlyAddedLib/NewlyAddedLib.csproj", "NewlyAddedLib/"]
RUN dotnet restore "NewlyAddedLib/NewlyAddedLib.csproj"
```

Is there a way to automatically populate that "block" inside the Dockerfile, just before build and keep the rest of the Dockerfile intact?

Maybe a tool/nuget package that inspects the references and inserts them?

Comment: The Dockerfile is just a text file, so you'd need some way of "compiling" your code into that Dockerfile, which isn't really a feature yet of either IDE.

Comment: I am not expecting that my IDE does that.